# owl.carousel help - Not showing enything

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

First time working with owl.carouse, and i cant seem to get it to work.

My html setup is this. And i want the PakWrapper to be the slide items. So i get 3 product li inside.

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="category-products">
    <div class="pakWrapper item">
        <ul class="product-list">
            <li class="item"></li>
            <li class="item"></li>
            <li class="item"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="pakWrapper item">
        <ul class="product-list">
            <li class="item"></li>
            <li class="item"></li>
            <li class="item"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

the owl code

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

      items : 1,
      loop : true,
      nav: true,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

  });

});

</script>
```

Can you tell me why it dont work??

Comment: dadd owl-crousel class and css

Comment: yeah i've added owl.carusel.css

Comment: any console error?

Comment: (index):229 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function

Comment: yeah. I've added jquery-2.1.4.min.js.

Comment: on which line TypeError:$().ready

Comment: Its on line 230. how can it say that the document.ready is wrong?

Comment: are you adding jquery after document.ready function

Comment: No only inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i don´t get why it. but i changed the `$` alias to `jQuery` and it worked.